# Getting a 'AttributeError at /login/authenticated', 'User' object has no attribute 'backend'

Tags: python, django, twitter-oauth

I'm using the Python-Oauth2 library found [here](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2), Django 1.3. I'll end up using the Twitter library located [here](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/).

I've searched everything I could on this, but I can't see why I'm getting this error. When someone else asked this question, they were told it was because they didn't call for an authenticate(), but I have that right above the login.

I've managed to figure out that the REASON it is failing is somehow drawn into the call to authenticate() with Django. I confirmed this by commenting out the login- which promptly gets rid of the error. Something about that authenticate, whether it's the profile/user information or something of that nature, is failing.

Here's the code from my views.py:

```
def twitter_authenticated(request):
    # Step 1. Use the request token in the session to build a new client.
    token = oauth.Token(request.session['request_token']['oauth_token'],
                        request.session['request_token']['oauth_token_secret'])
    client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)

    # Step 2. Request the authorized access token from Twitter.
    resp, content = client.request(access_token_url, "GET")
    if resp['status'] != '200':
        print content
        raise Exception("Invalid response from Twitter.")

    """
    This is what you'll get back from Twitter. Note that it includes the
    user's user_id and screen_name.
    {
        'oauth_token_secret': 'IcJXPiJh8be3BjDWW50uCY31chyhsMHEhqJVsphC3M',
        'user_id': '120889797',
        'oauth_token': '120889797-H5zNnM3qE0iFoTTpNEHIz3noL9FKzXiOxwtnyVOD',
        'screen_name': 'heyismysiteup'
    }
    """

    access_token = dict(cgi.parse_qsl(content))

    # Step 3. Lookup the user or create them if they don't exist.
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=access_token['screen_name'])
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        # When creating the user I just use their screen_name@twitter.com
        # for their email and the oauth_token_secret for their password.
        # These two things will likely never be used. Alternatively, you
        # can prompt them for their email here. Either way, the password
        # should never be used.
        user = User.objects.create_user(access_token['screen_name'], '%s@twitter.com' % access_token['screen_name'], access_token['oauth_token_secret'])

        # Save our permanent token and secret for later.
        profile = Profile()
        profile.user = user
        profile.oauth_token = access_token['oauth_token']
        profile.oauth_secret = access_token['oauth_token_secret']
        profile.save()

    # Authenticate the user and log them in using Django's pre-built
    # functions for these things.

    user = authenticate(username=access_token['screen_name'], password=access_token['oauth_token_secret'])
    login(request, user)

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the issue was the authenticate call in my authenticate view function was failing due to the password (which is actually the `access_token['oauth_token_secret']`).

So that we're on the same page, I'm talking about the `def twitter_authenticated(request):` function, that is included in the python-oauth2 github page itself, in the code example, in the views code section.

Due to the fact that I upgraded everything else, as well, along with Django 1.3, I had the wrong password in the `auth_user` table.

To summarize: simply look at the Django debugging output when loading your page (I'm assuming that you have `DEBUG = True` in your settings) and then narrow it down to which exact call. I'm pretty sure the function that fails for you, is the one that failed for me, though, which is

```
user = authenticate(username='blahblah', password=access_token['oauth_token_secret'])
```

So make sure the auth_user table/password field is the correct SHA1 of your `access_token['oauth_token_secret']`.

The reason I had the wrong one... I got a new computer, so I was installing all of the latest of everything, but didn't carry over the database data from my old computer.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue. I just noticed that the github page for Python-Oauth2 has the following message that's related to the views.py file specifically:

"NOTE: The following code was coded for Python 2.4 so some of the libraries and code here might need to be updated if you are using Python 2.6+."

I think I'm going to try downgrading to 2.5 temporarily just to narrow down whether it's a django 1.3 thing, or python.